Python: async function without await
Is this a true statement?

An async python function that does not include an await statement itself will not yield execution to any other async functions, even though it's invoked by an await call.

FastAPI example
from fastapi import FastAPI


import some_arbirtrary_library

app = FastAPI()


async def no_await():
    # this can be any code provided it does not 
    # include an await statement
    result = some_arbitrary_library.some_arbitrary_function()
    return result


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    # Belief: this will not ever yield execution to any other
    # async operation (e.g. other async endpoints) because \
    # the guts of the function 'no_await' do not await on anything
    result = await no_await()
    return {"message": result}
#... other app endpoints defined with async def


Is this a valid corollary to this?

Defining a function async that does not include an await statement does not provide any performance enhancements over using the function in a synchronous manner.


Not sure how python async/await works but your 2nd statement doesn't follow from the first as the first only mentions other async functions. Doesn't say anything about other sync functions

@apokryfos But sync functions are just called normally, there's no "yielding execution". So how could there be a performance benefit?

@Barmar I was thinking more of an async function can have a "fire and forget" kind of behaviour

@Barmar the performance benefit of asnyc is that while one async function (that is being awaited on) is, for example, waiting for a response from another server, other async functions (that are being awaited on) may execute.

Right. And if you don't use await to call the other function, you don't get that benefit. However, I think @apokryfos's point is that you can call an async function without await. It may return immediately after starting some background operation.

@Barmar  I'm considering the case where you do await the function, but the guts of that function don't await on anything

@Dave it does seem self-evident that merely adding the async keyword to a synchronous function will not improve performance so long as Python has a GIL. Once the GIL is gone, though, async functions could actually be scheduled in parallel without yielding execution.

@Dave this does imply that GIL-less implementations of Python that exist today could find use from synchronous-running async functions. This should be easy enough to benchmark -- just busy loop as you're doing, await that function call a couple hundred times, then run that python code through both CPython (GIL) and PyPy (No-GIL) and compare timings.

@AdamSmith Is there no way to slip an asynchronous yield in "under the hood"?; for example if you import some arbitrary module

@Dave meaning that the called function might appear to be synchronous, but actually yields execution somewhere? I can't say without some non-trivial amount of research, but I expect that this would be possible if it calls some function that's running native C code, but likely impossible with pure Python. Consider NumPy as an example of a Python package that uses the C API under the hood and might yield execution in some hidden way.

@AdamSmith even with busy loop, if other coroutines are waiting on i/o, and they can could somehow make progress on their i/o bound operations in the meantime, that would be a performance boost.

@AdamSmith numpy releases the GIL on many operations, but, AFAIK does not do anything async

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


An async python function that does not include an await statement
itself will not yield execution to any other async functions, even if
invoked by an await call.

Yes. Until it finishes, it will not give the control back to the event loop.

Defining a function async that does not include an await statement
does not provide any performance enhancements over using the function
in a synchronous manner.

Yes it is also True. async def is an indication that you're gonna use an IO async call therefore you'll use await for that. You don't have await? you don't need async def.
